# window scroll top function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется данный код:

```
$('#photos').animate({ num: 21300 - 700}, {
        duration: 5000,
        step: function (num){
            this.innerHTML = (num + 700).toFixed(0)
        }
    });
```

Как сделать так, что бы он начинал работать только тогда, когда осуществляется прокрутка экрана на 1000px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните весь код в условие с функцией [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Что-то типа такого:

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1000) {
  // ваш код
}
```